# byobu, ssh and an accidently closed fluxbox

Tags: ssh, byobu, fluxbox

So i was using fluxbox and had a terminal using ssh to connect to a server. This server automatically starts byobu for everyone who's connecting to him. At least until i accidently closed my fluxbox while still having the ssh connection working.
Now only the ssh connections from my machine won't use byobu but pure ssh instead. It's not that i mind that, actually i prefer it that way, but there is someone also using the machine i'm using and he wants to have byobu starting automatically.

And now i'm in a tight spot, kind of at least. I don't know how to activate the byobu session for a particular machine and i don't know how it was deactivated for only this machine? Is it possible, that the old session is still active on the server and just waits to get finished? And if that's the problem, how do i finish it?

Comment: Thank you, Dustin.
Five minutes ago i found my mistake.
The last command you posted (the export added to the .bashrc) was the one that i had totally forgotten about. After deleting my LC_BYOBU=0 from my .bashrc byobu started. This is embarrasing, and i guess it was a mixture of editing the own .bashrc and not reloading the bash. So after i closed my fluxbox the bash was restarted when i opened a new terminal. So byobu didn't start and i had totally forgotten about the flag (or dismissed it for not functioning, and so forgot about it.) Nevertheless i thank you for your help, Dustin. If i had ch

Answer (score 2):

Author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co) here :-)

There are several ways to have [Byobu](http://byobu.co) launch automatically at boot...

As the system administrator, you can set Byobu to launch automatically for all users by enabling that at the package level:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure byobu
```

Each local, non-administrator user on the system can override that system-wide setting above, by running:

```
byobu-enable
```

or

```
byobu-disable
```

And finally, anyone can export an environment variable locally on the system where they SSH from.  This variable will be passed over the SSH connection and if Byobu is running on the remote system, it will detect that and launch automatically if set.  To enable launching of Byobu by default when SSH'ing to another system simply:

```
echo "export LC_BYOBU=1" >> ~/.bashrc
```